# Single Item in Express.js POST request is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express

I am creating an Invoice App and have added many things with no issue to my SQlite DB but have run into an issue adding the total amount due to one of my tables.  I have no issues with the invoice name or paid amount in the POST request but for some reason the total due is becoming undefined when sent to the server side.

Here is my Express.js server code for the POST for the invoice table:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO invoices(name, user_id, paid, total_due, created) VALUES('${req.body.name}','${req.body.user_id}','${req.body.paid}','${req.body.total_price}',datetime('now', 'localtime'))`;
  console.log(req.body.total_price, req.body.paid, req.body.name)
  db.serialize(function() {
    db.run(sql, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({
          status: false,
          message: "There was an error creating invoice!"
        });
      }
```

and here is my Vue.js code for sending the data to the server"

```
  formData.append("name", this.invoice.name)
  formData.append("item_id", item_id)
  formData.append("description", description)
  formData.append("quantity", quantity)
  formData.append("price", price)
  formData.append("paid", this.invoice.paid)
  formData.append("total_due", this.invoice.total_price)
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  formData.append("user_id", user.id)
  this.loading = "Creating Invoice, please wait..."
  console.log(this.invoice.total_price)

  axios.post("http://localhost:3128/invoice", formData,
  {
    headers: {"x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")}
  }).then(res => {
    this.loading = ''
    if (res.data.status === true) {
      this.status = res.data.message
    } else {
      this.status = res.data.message
    }
  })
```

All data sends back to express just fine and into the invoices table.  When i run console.log on the front end it logs the invoice name, paid, total_price.  but when I have the server console.log the req.body for name, paid, total_price it only returns paid and name and total_due is undefined

Comment: `total_due` should be `total_price`.

Comment: Or `req.body.total_price` should be `req.body.total_due`. Either way, you need to use the same name in `formData` as you do in `req.body`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I didn't realize the naming had to match.  That took care of the issue.

Comment: Where did you think the properties in `req.body` come from, if not the names that you give it in `formData`?